# listview not get updating after successfull adding

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

Developing an app of angular2seedadvanced and trying to implement ngrx/store after adding new item it will successfully updating in my database but my view will not get updating.new to ngrx and typescript. am following

- http://bodiddlie.github.io/ng-2-toh-with-ngrx-suite/

my code files are here.

reducer.ts

```
 export default function HeroReducer(state = initialState, action: Action): HeroListState {
switch (action.type) {
    case HeroActions.LOAD_HEROES_SUCCESS: {
        return action.payload;
    }
    case HeroActions.ADD_HERO_SUCCESS: {

        return [...state, action.payload];
    }
}
```

action.ts

```
export class HeroActions {

static ADD_HERO = '[Hero] Add Hero';
addHero(hero): Action {

    return {
        type: HeroActions.ADD_HERO,
        payload: hero
    };
}

static ADD_HERO_SUCCESS = '[Hero] Add Hero Success';
addHeroSuccess(hero): Action {

    return {
        type: HeroActions.ADD_HERO_SUCCESS,
        payload: hero
    };
}
}
```

effect.ts

```
@Effect() addHero$ = this.update$
    .ofType(HeroActions.ADD_HERO)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .switchMap(list => this.listService.addItems(list))
    .map(list => this.heroActions.addHeroSuccess(list));
```

component.ts

```
constructor() {
 this.grocerys$ = store.select('list');
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadItems();
    this.store.dispatch(this.heroActions.loadHeroes());
};

addGrocery() {
    this.groceryList.itemName = this.grocery;
    this.listService.addItems(this.groceryList)
        .subscribe(
        () => {
        // do nothing
        })


this.store.dispatch(this.heroActions.addHeroSuccess(this.groceryList));
    this.grocery = '';

};
```

view.html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let grocery of (grocerys$ | async)">{{grocery.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

how should i solve this issue? Any help will highly appreciable.

Comment: Please add the html code of your view.

Comment: html code include.